# Is there an algorithm to reorder structure members to minimize alignment padding?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, language-design, memory-alignment

I have been creating a programming language and I've been experimenting with reordering of structure/record members for (memory) efficiency and performance, by default. At the moment, I reorder the members by largest to smallest (and by original source order if they are the same size). However, this doesn't minimize the alignment padding in all cases.

Is there an algorithm to reorder structure members to minimize alignment padding? (Is the problem inherently difficult to solve?) The algorithm must take into account the alignment of the member not just its size.

Example in C:

```
// Source Order
struct A { // size -> 10 Bytes
    int8  a
    int32 b;
    int16 c;
};
// Optimal Internal Order
struct A { // size -> 7 Bytes
    int32 b;
    int16 c;
    int8  a;
};

// Source Order
struct B { // size -> 20
    int8  a[7];
    int16 b[3];
    int8  c;
    int16 d;
};
// Optimal Internal Order
struct B { // Size -> 16
    int16 b[3];
    int16 d;
    int8  a[7];
    int8  c;
};
```

Comment: This question is meaningless without stating the alignment rules you want to enforce. E.g. the x86 architecture has no requirement for padding (with the exception of vector instructions). Padding to achieve alignment is a space vs. run time tradeoff.

Comment: What are your alignment constraints exactly? That n-bit integers have to be n-bit aligned?

Comment: @svick The _default_ alignment constraints: ints and floats: equal to its size; arrays: alignment of the element type; (simd) vectors: dependent of the vector type (could be 8 byte, 16 bytes, etc); records: biggest member's alignment. 

However, this is not true for types with user specified alignments.

Comment: In the case of C and generally C++, the address of the first member of a structure is supposed to be the same as the address of the structure, so the first member should not be reordered.

Comment: A good first guess: order them by size; largest first. A second guess: use `size % largest_alignment requirement` .

Comment: If all alignment requirements are powers of 2 and no member's size is less than its alignment requirement, then ordering by decreasing *alignment requirement* will be padding-optimal.  More specifically, if any padding at all is needed, it can all appear at the very end.

Comment: @j_random_hacker This is probably the best option for the average case. For the case when the _alignment requirement_ > _member's size_, this ordering could fail but in that case, I think the user should manually specify the packing and ordering.